# Namespaces and naming

Tags: php, coding-style, naming

I'm having some trouble working this one out, probably more than I should. This is a pretty large project, with a very clearly defined structure, with no obvious problems, but I can't seem to figure out the optimal solution for this case, even after reading several convention documents and such.

For example, given the following namespace:

```
\vendor\core\lib\view;
```

Obviously it refers to a "view" namespace...which technically also has a 'view' class in it:

```
\vendor\core\lib\view\view
```

This is clearly not ideal, but I can't come up with a better way to name these. Take for example the cache namespace:

```
\vendor\core\lib\cache;
```

Same deal, the cache class becomes confusing when inside this namespace:

```
\vendor\core\lib\cache\cache;
```

Should I just move these 'core' classes from their namespaces, and put them in the parent namespace?

```
\vendor\core\lib\cache (class)
\vendor\core\lib\cache\adapter\redis (class)
```

Or is there a better term to refer to these types of classes?

Pardon my circularity, it's a bit late and my head's not quite working in optimal condition.

Comment: It's difficult to decipher what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, class names should be uppercase and namespaces lowercase, so it's not "confusing" to do what you're doing:

```
use \vendor\core\lib\cache\Cache;
```

Comment: It may not be confusing, but it is a little untidy. If Cache is the only class in the cache namespace, then does it really need it's own namespace? `\vendor\core\lib\Cache` would be more appropriate. Alternatively, if there are more than one class in cache namespace, is the name `cache` really appropriate?

Comment: `By convention, class names should be uppercase and namespaces lowercase` - This is not the case (pun intended).